# Why does are my passwords in the Heroku Postgresql addon blank?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, heroku

I am trying to understand why my passwords in the Heroku Postgres add on are blank. Is this a security measure or a bug? Before I deployed to Heroku (and added the Heroku Postgres add on), I was able to retrieve the hashed passwords from the database. My project is the PERN stack.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Before I deployed to Heroku (and added the Heroku Postgres add on), I was able to retrieve the hashed passwords from the database."  How?  Now what happens instead when you do the same thing?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now all I get is blank passswords